# How do I do 'mount --bind' in /etc/fstab?

Tags: unix, mount, fstab, linux

I'm trying to add `mount --bind /proc/ /chroot/mysql/proc` to `/etc/fstab`. How can I do this?

Comment: See the third paragraph of the section "The third field" in `man fstab`: "An  entry  swap  denotes  a  file  or  partition  to  be used for swapping, cf.  swapon(8).  An entry ignore causes the line to be ignored.  This is  useful  to show  disk  partitions which are currently unused.  An entry none is useful for bind or move mounts." See also the previous section in `man fstab`, "The second field" that also mentions the use of "none".

Comment: In case anyone's wondering, it looks like you can no longer do the same thing on Mac OS X: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/197029/how-do-you-mount-bind-a-local-directory

Answer (score 268, accepted):

The `mount` command accepts `--bind` or `-o bind`.

In the `/etc/fstab` file, you can use the following line:

```
/source /destination none defaults,bind 0 0
```

Comment: Are you sure that the `defaults,bind` is necessary? I'm almost sure that `bind` would be enough.

Comment: just in case of situations on boot, i like to add `nofail,x-systemd.device-timeout=2` to the options....

Comment: @Reishin So, it would be like this? : /source /destination none defaults,bind,nofail,x-systemd.device-timeout=2 0 0 ?

Answer (score 117):

If I had a volume mounted at `/media/3tb-vol1/Private/`, and I wanted to bind it to `/srv/Private` I have a `/etc/fstab` like this.

```
/media/3tb-vol1/Private/ /srv/Private        none    bind
```

Answer (score 2):

In Addition to rely on an always existing drive, if you would use this entry to mount an external drive, the boot would fail while the drive is not connected.

In Addtion to the solve this, there is a known boot options for this ;)

- `nofail` ignores non existing mount points and continues regardless

```
/media/3tb-vol1/Private/ /srv/Private        none    bind,nofail
```

i would also suggest to see this as Reference [What is the difference between `nobootwait` and `nofail` in fstab](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/53456/what-is-the-difference-between-nobootwait-and-nofail-in-fstab) from Linux & Unix SE